# How set up second HDMI monitor with 10 bit color in windows 10?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport, color-depth

I have 2 equals LG 27UD58 monitors which connected to Radeon RX 550:

- The first connected via DisplayPort and have 10 bit color depts
- The second connected via Hdmi and have only 8 bit color depts

For the second monitor no other color optyions available while first can be set up with 8 and 6 color depst. Why this happened? How to setup 10 bit color via HDMI for second monitor in windows 10?

[image]

Comment: Did you enable the “HDMI ULTRA HD Deep Color” option in the display’s OSD menu?

Comment: Yes! it is enaqbled

Comment: Try changing the pixel format first, as per manual. The display apparently does not support 4:4:4 with 10 bit over HDMI.